# Passing value from Children component to a Parent Component in React when Routing happens

Tags: reactjs

This is the scenario of my issue

I have a **'Home'** container which render all the templates blocks using dynamic routing. There I'm getting document type of the page which renders according to routes. I need to pass this document type to **'Header'** to add a class to control style  of the logo. how can I achieve this?

Below is the way it declared in App.js

```
        <Router history={history}>
            <Header />
            {routes &&
              routes.map(route => (
                <Route
                  key={route.Guid}
                  exact
                  path={route.Path}
                  render={props => (
                    <Home />
                  )}
                />
              ))}
            <Footer />
          </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Header` is persistent on all `routes`, you can move it within the render method where you'll have document type available. Maybe even best option would be to create some kind of layout that would wrap every component of yours

```
<Router history={history}>
    {routes &&
        routes.map(route => (
            <Route
                key={route.Guid}
                exact
                path={route.Path}
                render={props => {
                    const Component = route.component;
                    return (
                        <Layout documentType={route.documentType}>
                            <Component {...props} />
                        </Layout>
                    )
                }}
            />
        )
    )}
</Router>
```

with `Layout` being something like

```
const Layout = ({ documentType, children }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header documentType={documentType} />
            {children}
            <Footer />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: In my web application code pasted with the question is on 'App.js". Document type comes in 'Home' Component/Container. Class need to be decide on 'Header' which is getting in Home component

Comment: What exactly is Home component in your case? Some kind of layout for other routes or?

Comment: Yes. Its like a common template rendering page/component for all the pages

Comment: Just think of my Layout component as your Home component, so it should work that way

Comment: Document type comes from Home Template it self. It need to pass it to sibling component in here its header